# get key by name from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a nested NSDictionary of NSDictionaries. 
I get the dictionaries in an NSArray *array and I iterate through them with `for (NSDictionary *frame in array)`

What I want is the name of the frame. For example [frame getName], is there any function for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your array looks like this

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>My First Frame</string>
        ...
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>My Other Frame</string>
        ...
    </dict>
    ...
</array>
```

Then you would use this to get the name:

```
for (NSDictionary *frame in array) {
    NSString *frameName = [frame objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

However, if your dictionaries do not actually contain your frame's name, then you're out of luck (in an array, elements are stored using an index, not with a key).

Now, you've also referred to "nested NSDictionaries of NSDictionaries" above. If you have for example the following structure, where the name is the key in the outer dictionary:

```
<dict>
    <key>My First Frame</key>
    <dict>
        <key>width</key>
        <integer>300</integer>
        <key>height</key>
        <integer>200</integer>
        ...
    </dict>
    <key>My Second Frame</key>
    <dict>
        <key>width</key>
        <integer>150</integer>
        <key>height</key>
        <integer>105</integer>
        ...
    </dict>
    ...
</dict>
```

Then you could use this:

```
for (NSString *frameName in [outerDict allKeys]) {
    NSDictionary *frame = [outerDict objectForKey:frameName];
    // now you have both the key (frameName) and the value (frame) to work with
}
```

Comment: It looks exactly as the second example, thank you, sorry for not explaining it clearly

Answer (score 1):

Not fully understand your question, do you mean to get object from Dictionary by `Key`

`[dict objectForKey:@"key"]` should got it.

And if you means have another `array` which stores all the sub dictionary objects, and you need know the specify sub-dictionary's key value in the root dictionary:

`[[rootDict allKeysForObject:theSpecifySubDictionary] lastObject]`

Comment: I think you meant "specific", instead of "specify".  "Specify" is the verb, "specific" is the noun.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *myTemp2Array = [myArray valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

This will walk an array (that contains dictionaries) and return all the values for the **@"Name"** key in a nice little array.